# How to extract the informations of bounding box from TensorOutput TFLite Model in Android?

Tags: python, android, object-detection

[Tensors Information (Input and Outputs)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0V4wd.png)

I've procced the inputs and have the outputs without error.
I want to extract the information from the outputs in android, but I don't know how to do it.

[Sample code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CWu5.png)

```
        var resized:Bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 320,320,true)
        val model = ModelJerawatAutoml.newInstance(this)

        // Creates inputs for reference.
        val normalizedInputImageTensor = TensorImage.fromBitmap(bitmap)

        // Runs model inference and gets result.
        val outputs = model.process(normalizedInputImageTensor)
        val locations = outputs.locationsAsTensorBuffer
        val classes = outputs.classesAsTensorBuffer
        val scores = outputs.scoresAsTensorBuffer
        val numberOfDetections = outputs.numberOfDetectionsAsTensorBuffer
   
        textView1.setText((locations.floatArray[0] ).toString())
        textView2.setText((locations.floatArray[1]).toString())
        textView3.setText((locations.floatArray[2]).toString())
        textView4.setText((locations.floatArray[3]).toString())
```

Can you guys tell me how to create the bounding box in android?
and also **I don't do real-time detection just only from the images**